# How to compare fields into AggregateFunction

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

sorry for my english ..

I need to compare the user'param(MonthYear / 6characters) with the field TxtDtVts (a date with 7 OR 8 characters)
If they match, it must return the fields "CodeTva" and "TauxTVA" by the desired Month

below is my collection "tickets":

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59e66bdda00472964e6a950b"),
    "Pharma" : "HEA00001",
    "TxtDtVts" : 2012016, // Or 22012016  (7 or 8 characts)
    "TxtHrsVts" : 842,
    "NumVts" : 845613,
    "NumEmp" : 19,
    "NumPoste" : 127,
     "PVHT" : 1.0575,
    "CodeTva" : 4,
    "TauxTVA" : 2.1,
    "PVTTC" : 1.08,
}
```

Here my end point and my aggregate function :

```
secureRoutes.route('/ticketTVA/month/:MonthYear') //  Example  012016

.get(function(req, res){
    var mois= req.params.month;

    Ticket.aggregate([ 

    {$project:{
        TxtDtVts:1,

        Correspondance: {
            $let: {
               vars: {
                  monthSubstring: { $substr: [ "$TxtDtVts", 0, -1 ] },
                  moisReq:{$substr: ["$mois",0,-1]},

               },
               in: { $cmp: [ "$$monthSubstring", "$$moisReq" ] }
            }
         }
    }},

      ],function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }
        console.log(result);
        res.json(result);
    });  
})
```

I tried to use $substr to convert data into string, save them in vars and use $cmp to compare them.

If i do that (without match before), i have an error :  `errmsg: 'aggregation result exceeds maximum document size (16MB)`
More, it's a bad way because TxtDtVts length change (1012016 OR 10012016)..
How can i compare this 2 data and if it match, return me "CodeTva" and "TauxTVA" ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: TxtDtVts appears to be an integer, not a string or a date.   Could you explain a little more how the 6 character input should match against the 7 or 8 character output?

Comment: The 6 characters of input represent MMYEAR.

Comment: So the input is a string, MMYYYY, and you are comparing that to a 7 or 8 digit integer that is structured how?   Looks like MDDYYYY or MMDDYYYY?

Comment: The 6 characters of input represent MMYEAR. The TxtDtVts represent DDMMYEAR. I need to compare two datas and get documents who concern the desired month.  Consider the input : 012016 . I need to verify if this input match with the 6 lasts characters of TxtDtVts (Ex: 1012016).

Comment: That's it Buzz. The input is a string of 6 characts and i must compare this with the field TxtDtVts (Int32).   Input -> MMYYYY  and TxtDtVts -> DMMYYYY or DDMMYYYY

Comment: Is it possible to avoid complexity by actually storing TxtDtVts as a real datetime instead of an int?

Answer (score 0):

Try this on for size:   Make your input an int, NOT a string.  It is easy to take your input and do so.  Then:

```
db.foo.aggregate([
  { $addFields: {
    "rc": {$eq: [{$divide:[{ "$subtract": [ "$date", input ] },1000000]},
                 {$trunc: {$divide:[{ "$subtract": [ "$date", input ] },1000000]}} ]}
  }}
  ,{ $match: {"rc":true}}
                ]);
```

The idea is to take a date like 8022013 (Feb 8, 2013) or 25121970 (Dec 25, 1970)
and subtract off the MMYYYY component.  So an input of 22013 (the int version of the string "022013", note how leading zero drops off) yields 8000000.   Division by 1000000 on a floating point and integer basis yields the same number (8).  If the DB date was 8032013, the diff is 8010000.   This yields 8 and 8.01 which are not equal.

Comment: I'll try to use $addFields but if there not  $match pipe in first in my aggregate function, i've always the same error : errmsg: 'aggregation result exceeds maximum document size (16MB)'..Can i compare this two values into $match pipe ?

Comment: I added the $match operator to catch only those dates that match.   There is no intermediate construction of a doc involved here; you should not bump into any 16MB limits.

Comment: I found a solution:                                                                         var mois= req.params.mois;
jrsDuMois= [];
var i = 1;
for (; i <= 31; i++)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution

```
jrsDuMois= [];
var i = 1;
for (; i <= 31; i++) {
jrsDuMois.push(parseInt(i+""+mois)); 
}
```

And i compare the field TxtDtVts with my array "jrsDuMois":

```
{ "$match": {
        "TxtDtVts": { "$in": jrsDuMois },
      }},
```